# Python unpack a list into distinct components for comparison

Tags: python, list, floating-point, int

I have the following Python data structure:

```
 successorGameState.getGhostPositions()
 [(6.0, 2.0)]
 newPos
 (3, 4)
```

I want to compare them the two to make sure they're not the same. Would it be best to unpack the first one into a couple ints or to modify to second to be floats like the first?

How does one go about doing that in Python, I've attempted both ways and met with extreme resistance  in both cases!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare them directly:

```
successorGameState.getGhostPositions()[0] != newPos
```

That compares two tuples, which are only equal if the contents are the same; comparing integers and floats works provided the floats represent whole numbers *exactly*.

You may need to test for a minimum difference between the floating point numbers and the integers, as they can former can *easily* be slightly off:

```
ghost_pos = successorGameState.getGhostPositions()[0]
if abs(ghost_pos[0] - newPos[0]) > 0.01 and abs(ghost_pos[1] - newPos[1]) > 0.01:
    # The differ enough
```

Adjust your tolerance as needed.

Comment: the output is so ugly though it's driving me crazy, isn't there a way i can make them the same?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve; when are the positions deemed not the same, for example?